# Move div to a different div in each slide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move a div with class 'move-button' to its closest `.et_pb_button_wrapper`. However doing this results in all instances of 'move-button' being repeatedly added to each `.et_pb_button_wrapper`.

I've tried wrapping the code in an each function but this has not worked.

```js
$('.et_pb_slide').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.move-button').appendTo('.et_pb_button_wrapper');
});
```

```css
.et_pb_slide_content,
.et_pb_button_wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: solid #fff 2px;
}

.et_pb_button_wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="et_pb_slides">
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I think I'm saying is for each slide, find it's `.move-button` and append it to `.et_pb_button_wrapper`. Obviously this is not what is happening.

[**jsfiddle:**](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/666004/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target `.et_pb_button_wrapper` relative to `button` element. `.find()`/`.children()` method can be used to target the desired element.

```
$('.et_pb_slide').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.move-button').appendTo($(this).find('.et_pb_button_wrapper') );
});
```

```js
$('.et_pb_slide').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.move-button').appendTo($(this).find('.et_pb_button_wrapper'));
});
```

```css
.et_pb_slide_content,
.et_pb_button_wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: solid #fff 2px;
}

.et_pb_button_wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_slides">
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_slide">
    <div class="et_pb_slide_content">
      <a class="move-button">See Range 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="et_pb_button_wrapper">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaah, I was so close. Thanks for the input, much appreciated.